# Neo4j COLLECT and SORT together

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j COLLECT is used to find all the adjecent nodes of a node .Suppose if we want to find all the adjacent nodes of a node together in SORTED ORDER.

I have tried the below approach, but it didn't work.

```
MATCH (ee:RECORD)-[:TAGGEDWITH]->(p:TAG)<-[:PARTOF]-(v:TAGTYPE)
RETURN p.tag_id as id,
       COLLECT( DISTINCT ee.record_id)  AS Records 
ORDER BY ee.record_id, p.NAME AS name,
         COUNT(*) AS n, v.NAME as group
```

Answer (score 4):

No, `COLLECT` is an aggregation function much like `COUNT` or `SUM`.

`MATCH` with a pattern is used to find adjacent nodes.

You would use an intermediate `WITH` with `ORDER BY` to sort the records before aggregating them.

```
MATCH (ee:RECORD)-[:TAGGEDWITH]->(p:TAG)<-[:PARTOF]-(v:TAGTYPE)
WITH p, ee
ORDER BY ee.record_id
RETURN p.tag_id as id, p.NAME AS name, v.NAME as group,
       COLLECT( DISTINCT ee.record_id)  AS records, 
       COUNT(*) AS n
```

Comment: I am not sure , if my question is understood correctly :-),COLLECT get some items, I just want those items to be sorted. Can I achieve this with your solution

Comment: I think it does. But in many use cases this is the wrong stage to sort the stuff in an array/collection, and that is my current issue. What if we already have an array/collection and we want to sort it? Or what if we don't want to change the ordering within the data manipulation stage of the query, but we prefer to display sorted results to the user? Array properties are much more important in graph databases than in relational databases, and too many functionalities seem to be missing in that area...

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be closer to what you were trying to achieve:

```
WITH [1,3,5,2,4] AS coll
UNWIND coll AS elems
WITH elems ORDER BY elems
RETURN COLLECT(elems);
// [1,2,3,4,5]
```

What it does is take a collection, unwind it ("un-collect it"), order it and then aggregate it back to a collection. I think this solution is a rather ugly hack, but it worked for me as a workaround.